# access local com port from a remote server

Tags: php, serial-port, local, remote-server

I have a custom POS system in PHP (on a remote server), which requires displaying the price on a Pole display device, which is connected through com port (on the local PC).

I want a way to access the local com port from a remote server.

Is that applicable?

Comment: php run server side, so in short, no

Comment: @Dagon, is there's any work around for this? I mean using Javascript or any other language.

Comment: seems like your approaching this with the wrong language set, the pc with the com device should be running an application to communicate with the remote server

Comment: does google serial help with this? http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial

Comment: If you are using Linux on the PC with a RS232 port, you could use [ser2net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ser2net/).

Comment: You can buy a serial over ethernet device which will convert the serial stream to TCP/IP in both directions. Then you can use a socket in your PHP/server side to talk to it. I have had good luck with Lantronix devices. http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/?tab=0

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a serial over ethernet device which will convert the serial stream to TCP/IP in both directions. Then you can use a socket in your PHP/server side to talk to it. I have had good luck with Lantronix devices. http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/?tab=0